# Match the value of ComboBox inside a DataGridView to another cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a `DataGridView` with a `ComboBox` column.
The ComboBox gets filled with a specific list of names and they are identical for every row in the `DataGridView`.

After I fill my `DataGridView`, I would like to do the following:

I want every Combo’s value to be set to the corresponding row’s “Table Columns” value, if exists.

[image]

I.e. in the picture above I want the value of the first Combo to be “id” (if it contains an item named “id”), the second to be “firstname”, etc.

If the value is not found, it should not select any value in the `ComboBox`.

**Update**: My current code that is not working

```
private void Mappings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    dgv.DataSource = tableColumns.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
    dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Table Columns";
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    comboColumn.HeaderText = "File Columns";
    foreach (var item in fileColumns)
        comboColumn.Items.Add(item);
    dgv.Columns.Add(comboColumn);
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        string tableColumnValue = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        row.Cells[0].Value = tableColumnValue;           
    }
}
```

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: @Moumit updated the question. Please take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trace the change .. **you almost did it**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] tableColumns = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

        string[] fileColumns = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "X" };

        dgv.DataSource = tableColumns.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();

        dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Table Columns";
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboColumn.HeaderText = "File Columns";
        foreach (var item in fileColumns)
            comboColumn.Items.Add(item);
        dgv.Columns.Add(comboColumn);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            string tableColumnValue = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            //Change is here
            if (fileColumns.Any(i => i == tableColumnValue))
            {
                row.Cells[1].Value = tableColumnValue;
            }
            //end change
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I did a similar thing:

1. Recognize which fields are of type `enum`
2. For the fiels of type `enum`, show a `ComboBox`in the cell of the `DataGridView` (containing all the possible values of the `enum`) instead of the simple text field.

I think you only need to change certain parts of the code to transform it to what you are trying to achieve:

```
public partial class TableView<CollectionType, ItemType> : Form
{

    public TableView(CollectionType elements)
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        // custom:
        this.DataGridView.DataSource = elements;
        AdaptColumnsToColumnValueType();

    }

    private void AdaptColumnsToColumnValueType()
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < this.DataGridView.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            var column = (DataGridViewColumn)this.DataGridView.Columns[columnIndex];
            if (column.ValueType.IsEnum)
            {
                ReplaceColumnInDatagridView(
                    oldColumn: column,
                    newColumn: CreateComboBoxWithEnums(column));
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReplaceColumnInDatagridView(DataGridViewColumn oldColumn, DataGridViewColumn newColumn)
    {
        int columnIndex = oldColumn.Index;
        this.DataGridView.Columns.Remove(oldColumn);
        this.DataGridView.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, newColumn);
    }

    private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateComboBoxWithEnums(DataGridViewColumn replacedEnumColumn)
    {
        var comboboxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        comboboxColumn.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(replacedEnumColumn.ValueType);
        comboboxColumn.DataPropertyName = replacedEnumColumn.DataPropertyName;
        comboboxColumn.Name = replacedEnumColumn.Name;
        return comboboxColumn;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DataGridViews RowsAdded event.

Edit: cmb is your ComboBoxColumn

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
   //Check if comboboxcolumn contains the value                
   if(cmb.Items.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value)) {
   //Set the value
     dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["cmb"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
         }
    }
```